# How can I list all labels using the TFS command line tool 'tf.exe'?

Tags: command-line, tfs

I want to produce a list of all of the labels using the command line tool `tf.exe`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tf labels /owner:*`

By default the `labels` command only lists labels that you own yourself.

If you want to limit the labels output you can filter the labels:

`tf labels /owner:* 0.1*`

The above will output only the labels with a name beginning with "0.1".

For more info:

- [Labels Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t21wc9ca.aspx)

Comment: Sadly it dies with `System.OutOfMemoryException`. Is there a way to ask for the labels in parts? Like first 10k, than second 10k etc.?